# Java Threads consistency issue

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have a use case which i have replicated in a small code sample :

```
package com.learning.thread;

public class ThreadInterupt {
    public volatile int count;

    public synchronized int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
    public synchronized void increment(){
        count++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadInterupt local = new ThreadInterupt();
        Thread firstThread = new Thread( new myThread(local));
        Thread secondThread = new Thread( new myThread(local));

        firstThread.start();
        secondThread.start();

        Thread.sleep(10);
        firstThread.interrupt();
        secondThread.interrupt();

    }
}

class myThread implements Runnable{
    static void threadMessage(String message) {
        String threadName =
            Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.format("%s: %s%n",
                          threadName,
                          message);
    }

    ThreadInterupt global;

    public  myThread(ThreadInterupt local){
        global = local;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int i=0;
        while(i<5){
            if(Thread.interrupted()){
                threadMessage("Got Killed");
                break;
            }
            i++;
            global.increment();
            threadMessage(String.valueOf(global.getCount()));
        }
    }
}
```

I have two threads which shares a variable count , Which is defined volatile . I have two methods in the ThreadInterupt class where i increment and get the count variable, Both defined synchronized .  My Problem is that while i expect the second thread to get the incremented value correctly it fails to do so . I am adding the output as well.

```
Thread-0: 1
Thread-1: 2
Thread-0: 3
Thread-0: 5
Thread-0: 6
Thread-0: 7
Thread-1: 4
Thread-1: 8
Thread-1: 9
Thread-1: 10
```

As you can see after thread-0 prints 7 , Thread-1 prints 4 . My assumption here is that the Thread-1 entered the synchronized method get and got blocked by the increment method of thread-0 , And once it thread-0 got completed it prints out the get . I am not convinced with this . Can someone help ?

// Edit , as codeBencher suggests ,

This may be because of that delay . When i added a synchronized print method  to the ThreadInterupt class  , This works fine.

```
public synchronized void print(String threadName){
  System.out.println(threadName+String.valueOf(count));
 }
```

and in the run method

```
global.increment();
global.print(Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

Comment: Well, a thread could be interrupted after calling `increment` but before calling `getCount()`..

Comment: There are a lot of statements between your `global.getCount()` and `System.out.format()`. Execution could 've moved to thread0 when thread1 was in any of those statements.

Comment: Nice example of a classic race condition.  It isn't enough to synchronize individual operations.  You have to ensure the *behavior* you expect occurs synchronously.

Comment: I think @Codebender  , You are correct . Editing the answer

Comment: I hope that you realize that the behaviour you are seeing here has nothing to do with interrupts.  You could get rid of that part of the example and the behaviour would be identical.

Comment: The other thing is that is forcing a multi-threaded code to run the threads in a particular sequence is most likely going to make it effectively single threaded.  Certainly, it would in this case.  Kind of defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a race-condition.  The JVM will not guarantee how many cycles to devote to either thread.  So the volatile worked, as you do not see the same number displayed twice.  But the order in which the commands were executed across the two threads were not as you may have expected.  It did not go t-1 do a command, now t-2 do a command, now t-1 again and now t-2.  Instead it might have done it t-1, t-1, t-1, t-2, t-1, t-1, t-2, t-2, t-2, t-2, t-2.... and so forth and so on.  To force it to go t-1, t-2, t-1, t-2.. in that order, you would have to use other techniques using classes that are in the [concurrent package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

For example one common technique is to use a ConcurrentLatch or a Future to wait for one or more other threads to finish.  A very cool one that may work for a countdown (or count up) system like this is the [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html), where t-1 and t-2 can each increment a volatile integer, then wait for the CyclicBarrier to let them continue.

Comment: I took a quick look into CyclicBarrier , But i feel its more complicated for my use case .  I always have only  two threads where both consumes the variable and modifies it .  I will look into ConcurrentLatch